# Does Omnipage for OmniPage for Document Conversion and Indexing Platform (DCIP) has the capability to perform compression on scanned documents

Tags: compression, ocr, printers

I have an application that is using Omnipage for DCIP for scanned documents and OCR from printer. May I know does it have the compression ability for the scanned documents and if have, how do I set compression in setting of Omnipage for DCIP?